Можно ли в 1С УТ 11.5 сделать выбор начисление баллов или скидка?
Можно ли что бы кассир в режиме РМК выбирал одну из этих бонусных систем:

начисление баллов 10%
скидка 5%

По отдельности эти акции создавать умею.

Посмотрите по данным ссылкам:

Управление торговыми операциями в вопросах и ответах
Конфигурация "Управление торговлей". Редакция 11.5. Описание

